# Перезагрузка xml-документа на JS

Tags: javascript, xml

Требуется раз в день обновлять xml документ с сервера и получать данные с него. Каким методом в JS лучше воспользоваться?
Мой код:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_eng_utf8.xml', false);
xhr.send();
var parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText, "text/xml");
xmlDoc = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Valute")[11];
xmlDoc = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Value")[0].innerHTML.replace(',','.');
```

Comment: Дело в том, что на сайте иногда появляется предыдущий курс валют. Хотелось бы предостеречь себя и раз в день обновлять данные с сервера.

Comment: Можно сказать, что никак.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 т.е. курс валют останется статичным и при запросе будет показывать всегда одно и то же?